# Unsupported Media Type (415) with Generic Put or Post

Tags: java, generics, post, restlet, put

Aloha!

I was trying to implement a generic put or post method in Restlet. (I was able to implement a generic Get method without issue.)

Here is the relevant portion of my server resource (interface) file:

```
@Post
public <T> void insert( T object ) ;   //  non-idempotent update/create
```

Here is the relevant portion of my server resource (implementation) file:

```
//  non-idempotent create/update
public <T> void insert( T object )
{ }
```

I have tried both of the following in my Restlet client:

```
clientResource.insert( newUser ) ;
clientResource.<User>insert( newUser ) ;
```

However, both of these result in the following client side exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" Unsupported Media Type (415) - Unsupported Media Type
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:612)
at org.restlet.engine.resource.ClientInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInvocationHandler.java:264)
at $Proxy8.store(Unknown Source)
at storage.client.Client.main(Client.java:53)
```

Thus, it appears that there is some sort of marshaling (to the actual server put method -- insert()) that is failing.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Take care,

Darwin

Answer (score 0):

I think you've run into this known bug:

https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/426

There's some background discussion of it here:

http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=2910995#messagefocus

Comment: For what it's worth, I work around this in my project by just having explicit versions of my interface for different concrete classes.

Comment: Andy, would you happen to have a sample of your working implementation that you can share?